# SQL get text between 2nd last and 3rd last dash

Tags: sql, substring

I have some data that looks like this:

```
20170101 - Wal-Mart #111-1234-5687789-MC000555555

20170101 - Target -1235-56444878 - MC000555555
```

I want to use a SQL query to get the string between the 2nd last and 3rd last dash, so the results would be.

```
1234

1235
```

How can this be accomplished?  Since the names of the stores can have dashes, it's not reliable to start counting dashes from the beginning, unless there's some kind of trick I'm unaware of.

Thanks.

Comment: which database? sql-server? mysql? oracle? or you want an ansi-sql solution?

Comment: first sample it's between 3rd and 4th

Comment: @McNets 2nd **last** and 3rd **last** dash is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @LIvanov I know, but have a look at `Wall-Mart`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> create table test (data varchar(100));
> insert into test values
> ('20170101 - Wal-Mart #111-1234-5687789-MC000555555'),
> ('20170101 - Target -1235-56444878 - MC000555555');
>
>
> WITH Rev As
> (
>     SELECT REVERSE(data) data
>     FROM test
> )
> , Pos AS
> (
>     SELECT data,
>            CHARINDEX('-', data, CHARINDEX('-', data, 0) + 1) + 1 AS PIni,
>            CHARINDEX('-', data, CHARINDEX('-', data, CHARINDEX('-', data, 0)+1)+1) AS PFin
>     FROM   Rev
> )
> SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(data, PIni, PFin - PIni))
> FROM   Pos;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 1234             |
> | 1235             |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c17c2fb29c527c857647b2de226ddf84)*

Comment: It's close, but it brings in the wrong text if there's an extra dash.  I'll try monkeying around with REVERSE to see if there's a way to get it to work, but this is a new area of SQL for me.

Comment: with reverse you can get it

Comment: Yep, I got it with reverse.  I used reverse a lot, but it works so whatever.  Not dealing with millions of rows so if it's inefficient it will still be ok.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how else would you approach this, unless you count dashes. Since you cannot start counting from the beginning of the string (because of the names of the stores), maybe you can count from the end. So a combination of the following should do the thing for you:

- [SQL reverse](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040(v=sql.110).aspx) - reverses the string (so you can "count from the end")
- [SQL charindex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) - gets the index of a given char in a given string
- [SQL substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) - so you can extract the needed data, once you know where the second last and third last dashes are

Hope this helps, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest one `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` inside another, like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(data,'-',-3),'-',1) FROM `test`
```

This will extract the last three "portions", then extract the first "portion" from that.